# How to interact with events in the Slack API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack-api

I'm trying to experiment with events like 'reaction_added' in Slack but I'm not sure how to call them. I've been referring to http://api.slack.com as well as the slack-node npm module but I haven't had any luck. Can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: You don't "call" an event... an event is something that you get told about. E.g., when a reaction is added, the `reaction_added` event will be sent to your bot over the WebSocket it's connected on. Maybe you can clarify what you're trying to do? Are you trying to respond to reactions or are you trying to add your own reaction?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm trying to respond to a reaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Botkit framework, it'd look like this

```
controller.on('reaction_added',function(bot,event) {
 bot.reply(event.item, "I love " +  event.reaction)
})
```

If you use another langage/framework, you should specify it, it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks. This is really useful, but could you explain what reaction.item is? I thought that reply could only take an incoming message object.

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo. I corrected it. event.item will indeed be the message to which the reaction was added (see [docs](https://api.slack.com/events/reaction_added)), as you expected.